# Typesetting small inline commutative triangles

Tags: spacing, arrows, commutative-diagrams

Below is an excerpt from Anton Geraschenko's [stack notes](https://stacky.net/files/written/Stacks/Stacks.pdf).

How can I typeset the triangle of arrows? I thought of using `underset` somehow but I don't get a long enough arrow and the spacing doesn't work, not to mention I don't know how to produce the small diagonal arrows.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried (MWE). This seems like one of those typical "one can crack it with the TikZ sledgehammer" problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack notes?  Did someone mention stack?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath,graphicx}
\stackMath
\newcommand\triar[3]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$%
  #1%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\rightarrow#3\leftarrow$\kern-4pt}%
  \stackunder[0pt]{\xrightarrow{\kern\wd0}}%
    {%
      \rotatebox[origin=r]{-20}{$\rightarrow$}%
      \raisebox{-2pt}{$#3$}%
      \rotatebox[origin=l]{+20}{$\leftarrow$}%
    }%
  #2%
  $}}%
}
\begin{document}
whose objects are $\mathcal{P}$ morphisms to $Y$, with 
\(
\left\{\triar{X_i}{X}{Y}\right\}
\)\medskip

but not this: 
\(
\left\{\triar{X_i}{X}{Y_\text{long middle element}}\right\}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Funny how 'stack' popped up in a different context :)

Comment: @Arrow Yup.  Around here, I am Mr. Stack-it.

Comment: Or maybe Friar Stack-it? :o)

Comment: @Bernard Wouldn't that be Friar St**u**ck?  I'm that too, all too often.

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stuck Exchange then!

Comment: Dear @StevenB.Segletes Mr Stack-it, could you include a similar macro for small vertical maps? That is, something smaller than a `\smallmatrix` with three rows?

Comment: @Arrow Can you provide a web pointer to what you mean by "small vertical maps"?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want to typeset arrows of the form `\begin{smallmatrix}X\\ \downarrow\\ Y \end{smallmatrix}` often inline, or as subscripts. For this purpose, the diagram generated by the above code is too big. For instance I want to write something like `\mathrm{T}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}X\\ \downarrow\\ Y \end{smallmatrix}\right)` without having the vertical diagram so tall. Perhaps it's possible to shrink it nicely?

Comment: @Arrow To force it to fall within `\baselineskip` size, for inline use, `\usepackage{scalerel}`.  Then, define `\newcommand\vertmap[2]{{
  \scalerel*{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\\downarrow\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\right)}{
    \strut}
}}` and use as `Here is \(\mathrm{T}\vertmap{X}{Y}\) inline.`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes amazing, thank you! If it's alright, I have two more requests: 1) is it possible to make the scaling factor explicit in the code, so I could play with it? 2) is it possible to include an argument for a label to the right of the vertical arrow, in a way that will still keep the arrow centered?

Comment: @Arrow As to your first question, `\newcommand\vertmap[3][1]{{
  \scalerel*{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\\\downarrow\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\right)}{
    #1}
}}
\newcommand\bigstrut{\rule[-2pt]{0pt}{10pt}}
Here is \(\mathrm{T}\vertmap{X}{Y}\) inline and 
\(\mathrm{T}\vertmap[\bigstrut]{X}{Y}\).`  You can play with the dimensions of `\bigstrut`.

Comment: @Arrow As to the 2nd question, 1) is the label inside the parens? 2) is it OK if the label is the same size as the map from/to labels?

Comment: Dear @StevenB.Segletes, the parentheses are not necessary. The label is right next to the arrow, on the right. (Like a rotated `\overset`.) I am not sure I understood your second question.

Comment: @Arrow Something like this?  `\newcommand\vertmap[4][1]{{\scalerel*{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}#2\\\downarrow\smash{\rlap{\kern.3pt\raisebox{.3ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\scriptscriptstyle#4$}}}}\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\right)}{#1}}}
\newcommand\bigstrut{\rule[-2pt]{0pt}{10pt}}
Here is \(\mathrm{T}\vertmap{X}{Y}{}\) inline and 
\(\mathrm{T}\vertmap[\bigstrut]{X}{Y}{\alpha}\).`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes! Infinite thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\tricd}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    baseline={([yshift=-axis_height]mycd)},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every matrix/.append style={
      name=mycd,
      nodes={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt}
      },
    row sep=0pt, column sep=12pt
    ]
    #1\ar[rr]\ar[to=mycd-2-2.west]\&\&#2\ar[to=mycd-2-2.east]\\
    \&#3
  \end{tikzcd}%
  }
  
\begin{document}
whose objects are $\mathcal{P}$ morphisms to $Y$, with 
\(
\left\{\tricd{X_i}{X}{Y}\right\}
\)\medskip

but not this: 
\(
\left\{\tricd{X_i}{X}{Y_\text{long middle element}}\right\}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for [their solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678935/101651) to the vertical alignment problem.